# Is the number of elements of I equal to J in the product of two ideals IJ

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, ideals

It is said that the product of two ideals $I$, $J$ of a ring $R$ is the set of finite sums of the form $x_iy_i$ If $I={\langle x_1,x_2,x_3\rangle}$ and $J={\langle 1\rangle}$. 
According to the definition it implies that $IJ={\langle x_1y_1\rangle}$ but also $\langle x_2y_1,x_3y_1\rangle$ stays in $IJ$. I am confused at this point: Why it is not defined as the product of finite sums of the form $x_iy_j$? Would you help me please? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Note that although you applied the tag `commutative-algebra`, you do not specify in the body text (or title) that ring $R$ is a commutative ring.

Comment: I don't understand the last edit to the title.  Previously the Question had asked about the definition of the product of two ideals $IJ$ in a ring.  Now the title asks about "the number of elements of $I$ equal to $J$" in a somewhat ambiguous context.  Perhaps you should consider going back to the old title?

Comment: The Question has gone from being poorly phrased to worse.  Presumably you want to ask about defining the product of two ideals, but you not clarified any point that I've asked about, giving the impression that you have abandoned this request.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Denote the containing ring by $R$.

I'll assume that for the ideals $I,J$, you intended
$$I = (x_1,x_2,x_3),\;\;J = (y_1)$$
Then by definition, $IJ$ is the ideal consisting of all finite sums of products of the form $xy$, where $x \in I$ and $y \in J$.

But since ideals are closed under addition, that means $IJ$ is the ideal *generated* by all products of the form $xy$, where $x \in I$ and $y \in J$.

Let $H = (x_1y_1,x_2y_1,x_3y_1)$.

Claim $IJ = H$.

Clearly $H \subseteq IJ$, since the generators of $H$ are also generators of $IJ$.

To show the reverse inclusion, it suffices to show that each of the generators of $IJ$ is in $H$, i.e., $xy \in H$, for all $x,y$ with $x \in I$ and $y \in J$.

Thus, let $x \in I$ and $y \in J$.

Then $x = ax_1 + bx_2 + cx_3$, and $y=dy_1$, for some $a,b,c,d \in R$, hence
$$xy = (ax_1 + bx_2 + cx_3)(d y_1)$$
which, when expanded, is clearly in $H$ [since $H= (x_1y_1,x_2y_1,x_3y_1)]$.

Comment: It's a good answer to a less than good Question.  There's a lot of ground to be covered here, not only *why* the product of ideals is defined the way it is (despite some ambiguity in context qua commutative rings), but also respecting the number of generators required for the product ideal.